# Exposing my virginity status to my future partner

Tags: nikah, sin, sex

Assalamu'alaikum.I am 19 and a niqabi.I was physically and mentally abused by my Step dad since aged 8 been forced to accept for the well being of my motherand also forced sometimes to watch adult movies with him. At age 14 I nearly committed murder since then he stopped abusing me. I grew up hating and fearful of men. I became too matured for my age while reading about my religion Islam, started seeking forgiveness till now I am still asking for mercy.My mom died so i force myself out of my comfort zone and Start to date last year in an halal way since it's obligatory to get married but the guy has been asking me a lot about my virginity status I changed the topic each time but he then got really angry and cut the call on me while talking.I am mentally exhausted keeping this secret and I can't bring myself to lie to him.Please can I explain this to him?

Comment: We are not an advice group and we can not divine how a specific person will react to something. Also see https://islamqa.info/en/answers/136507/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the terms of the marriage agreement. If virginity is a stipulated condition in the marriage contract, the man has the right to annul the marriage if it is proven otherwise.

[Reference](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa56962)

Also, according to some scholars if a girl has lost her virginity outside of a valid marriage, she is still considered a virgin. A valid marriage is necessary for losing virginity.

[Reference](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa105667)